# Is there a way to reuse Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.UserCredential object to authorize SpreadsheetsService?

Tags: c#, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to use the Google Drive and Spreadsheets APIs from a C# console app. I'd like to authorize both services using user credentials with a `FileDataStore` so that I don't have to reauth my app every single time it runs. Below is how I'm authorizing my Drive service object:

```
var userCredential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync
(
  new ClientSecrets 
  { 
    ClientId = "[clientID]", 
    ClientSecret = "[clientSecret]" 
  },
  new [] 
  { 
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive",    
    "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds" 
  },
  "[userName]",
  CancellationToken.None,
  new FileDataStore("MyApp.GoogleDrive.Auth.Store")
).Result;

var driveService = new DriveService
(
  new BaseClientService.Initializer
  {
    HttpClientInitializer = userCredential,
    ApplicationName       = "MyApp",
  }
);
```

For the Spreadsheets service, I'm authorizing as prescribed by [this guide](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/#authorizing_requests_with_oauth_20), but every time I run my app, I have to open a browser to the given auth URL and  manually copy in the access token to get it to work.

**Is there a way to auth once, obtain the user credentials as above, and use them with both services? Note, I'm authorizing with both the Drive and the Spreadsheets scope, so I don't think there's a problem with that.**

I've tried to make it work like this, but I keep getting 400 Bad Request errors when I attempt to insert rows into my spreadsheet:

```
var auth = new OAuth2Parameters 
{ 
  ClientId     = "[clientID]",
  ClientSecret = "[clientSecret]",
  RedirectUri  = "[redirectUri]",
  Scope        = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds" ,
  AccessToken  = userCredential.Token.AccessToken,
  RefreshToken = userCredential.Token.RefreshToken,
  TokenType    = userCredential.Token.TokenType,
};

var requestFactory = new GOAuth2RequestFactory(null, "MyApp", auth);

var spreadsheetsService = new SpreadsheetsService("MyApp") 
{ 
  Credentials    = new GDataCredentials(userCredential.Token.TokenType + " " + userCredential.Token.AccessToken),
  RequestFactory = requestFactory,
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is there a way to auth once, obtain the user credentials as above, and use them with both services?

Yes. Provided you have included all scopes and have requested offline access, then you'll get a refresh token which you can store and reuse to get access tokens as needed. Obv you need to consider the security implications.

A 400 bad request doesn't sound like an OAuth issue. I think you have two questions/issues here and it might be worth starting a new thread. Include  the http request/response for the 400 in your question.

Comment: You're absolutely right. My error actually has nothing to do with authentication. It's further down the line.